# building library variants with scons

Tags: scons

I have an existing C library that's built with scons (the library has it's own
SConscript). This code now contains two variations controlled by `#ifdef`s. How
do I tell scons to build two variants of this library that can live side by
side (so applications can link against the appropriate variation)?

Conceptually, it's something like this:

```
driver_sources = [ ... ]
env.Library('drivers', driver_sources)

env.Library('drivers_withflag', driver_sources, 
            CPPDEFINES += ['FLAG'])
```

SCons (understandably) doesn't like using the same source list for different
outputs with different environments because the intermediate object names
conflict.

I'm not sure whether to approach this problem by somehow deriving a new
Builder for `drivers_withflag` objects, or whether I should include my library's
SConscript twice with some parameter to specify the `#defines` (and I could put
each variant in its own build directory). Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to some relevant documentation: http://www.scons.org/doc/1.1.0/HTML/scons-user/x1392.html

I think it would go something like this

```
driver_sources = [ ... ]

env.Library('libdrivers', driver_sources)

env_flag = env.Clone()

env_flag.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['FLAG'])

flag_objects = [os.path.splitext(src)[0] + '_flag' + 
  env['OBJSUFFIX'] for src in driver_sources]

d_wf = [env_flag.Object(tgt, src) for tgt,src in 
  zip(flag_objects, driver_sources)]

env_flag.Library(d_wf)
```

This would go directly inside your current SConscript file, however you could also take a look at this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463907/scons-how-to-use-the-same-builders-for-multiple-variants-release-debug-of-a-pr)

You could use the steps outlined there in whatever file calls your library's SConscript file to setup two environments, then just call the SConscript twice with each one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. `driver_sources` is a list of files, so with your solution, scons complains, "more than one source given for single source builder." Trying to build the library directly from the sources results in the problem that I explained in the question where the environments conflict in producing the same intermediate object file names.

Comment: Ah I see, yes I only worked out a simple example with one test file.  Maybe there is some alternative to Object?  Or pehaps some sort of for loop to create a list of Objects, then maybe you can build the library from that list of objects.. kinda shooting in the dark here now though.

Comment: indeed, I can use a list comprehension to create a list of Objects: `d_wf = [env_flag.Object(src + '.flag', src) for src in driver_sources]`. I still forget sometimes that in scons I've got the full power of python at my disposal. :) If you edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Good stuff. scons is actually my first real world introduction to python so I'm a little new at it.  Does that look good now?  Library knows what to do with a list of objects, right?  I'm assuming it does because scons is awesome that way.